# How to disable drop table and column when using mvn liquibase:diff?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, spring-data-jpa, liquibase

I'm setting up a release process to upgrade our production environment as easily as possible.

To achieve that concerning database, I've chosen liquibase.
Each time an environment is upgrade :

1. The code is deliver on servers,
2. `mvn liquibase:diff` is run to generate a changeLog with previous version
3. `mvn spring-boot:run` is run to start the application and execute liquibase with the new changeLog, and so, adapt the database from code entity freshly delivered.

The problem is that if a **field** in a java `@Entity` is, for example, **moved** to an other entity, **liquibase** will remove the column without transfering data to the new field location.

So my question is, can we configure liquibase to **avoid** column and table **drop** ? To be able to copy datas to their new locations, and after that, effectively remove the column (or table) for good ?

We're using **spring-boot 2.1.2** and the **liquibase maven plugin 3.4.1**. Our database is on **MySQL 5.7.27**.

I've try to find how to export all database **creation/alteration** `changeSet` in one `changeLog.xml` and all **drop** `changeSet` in an other `changeLog.xml`.
Like that we can execute between these two `changeLog`, a third `changeLog` dedicated to copy data to thier new location.
Bu didn't find solution in liquibase documentation : https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/diff.html

### To illustrate my example :

**v1**:

```java
@Entity
public class Person {
     private long id;
     private String name;
     private String phoneNumber;
}
```

Became

**v2**:
(creation of entity **Phone** to replace field *phoneNumber* of entity **Person**)

```java
@Entity
public class Person {
     private long id;
     private String name;
     private Phone phone;
}

@Entity
public class Phone {
    private long id;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String brand;
}
```

So when **v2** is delivered on server and `mvn liquibase:diff` is run, the result changeLog will **drop** column *phoneNumber* and create column *phone* in table **person**. 
Without transfering data from table **person**, filed *phoneNumber* to the new table **phone** in field *phoneNumber*.

I want to execute changeLog (manually wrote) that copy **Person.phoneNumber** to new entity **Phone.phoneNumber**.

Is that possible ? Or there is any trick to do that properly ? Or maybe I'm using liquibase in bad way to achieve that ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something, but as far as I understand, `diff` is not the all-powerful-tool which will absolve you of any responsibility.

In some cases you have to write changeSets yourself and I think this is one of them.

Since `diff` is indeed a very powerful command, it has it's shortcomings.

Check out this article: [The Problem With Database Diffs](http://www.liquibase.org/2007/06/the-problem-with-database-diffs.html)

> Theoretically, a diff tool could also check for new, updated, and
>   missing data between database, but in practice this cannot work for
>   two reasons:
>
> - Performance. As your data set grows, the amount of information to compare grows until it is unmanageable.
> - Changing Data. During development, test data is often added to the development database that shouldn’t be copied into other databases.
>     Also, new data may be added to testing and production databases that
>     should not be deleted just because it doesn’t exist in the development
>     database.

In your case, I'd do something like this:

1. Create a new table `phone`
2. Add column `person.phone_id`
3. Copy data from `person.phone_number` to `phone.phone_number`
4. Copy data from `phone.id` to `person.phone_id`
5. Create foreign key constraint between `person` and `phone`
6. Drop `person.phone_number`

The code could be like this:

```
<createTable tableName="phone">
    <column name="id" autoIncrement="true" type="bigserial">
        <constraints primaryKey="true" primaryKeyName="pk_phone"/>
    </column>
    <column name="phone_number" type="varchar(30)"/>
    <column name="brand" type="varchar(255)"/>
</createTable>
<addColumn tableName="person">
    <column name="phone_id" type="bigserial"/>
</addColumn>
<update tableName="phone">
    <column name="phone_number" valueComputed="(select p.phone_nubmer from person p)"/>
</update>
<comment>Assuming that person.phone_number is unique</comment>
<update tableName="person">
    <column name="phone_id" valueComputed="(select p.id from person p where p.phone_number = phone_number)"/>
</update>
<addForeignKeyConstraint baseTableName="person" baseColumnNames="phone_id"
    constraintName="person_phone_id_phone_id_fk"
    referencedTableName="phone" referencedColumnNames="id"/>
<dropColumn tableName="person" columnName="phone_number"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. We effectively decided to do more by ourselves with changeSets and some sql scripts. We make a dump of our old database, run liquibase to update schema and finally copy data from dump to their new location in the updated database.